# Using macros in \DeclareGraphicsRule statement using shell command

Tags: luatex, shell-escape

I am currently working on a document which i am compiling under both linux and windows. 
As one of the images I use is a tif image, I'd like to have lualatex converting it on-runtime to a format it understands.

Therefore, I managed to do this under linux using

```
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}%
{%
  `convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`-tif-converted-to.png %
}
\AppendGraphicsExtensions{.tif}
```

This however is not portable to windows because of the `dirname` and `basename` commands (as installing ImageMagick makes `convert` available).

Therefore, I would like to use the file parsing from latex to do this, but I could not find my way around it. 
The code I am currently trying to use is :

```
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*\dirname[1]{\filename@parse{#1}\filename@area}%
\newrobustcmd*\basename[1]{\filename@parse{#1}\filename@base}%
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}%
{%
  `convert #1 \dirname{#1}/\basename{#1}-tif-converted-to.png %
}%
\makeatother
\AppendGraphicsExtensions{.tif}
```

However, `\DeclareGraphicsRule` seems to just ignore I have used macros in my command.

So my question is the following :

- What am I doing wrong ?
- Is there a way around it ?

**EDIT :** Slightly changing the working command

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The conversion via shell escape is added by package `epstopdf`. In TeX Live it is automatically loaded, if pdfTeX/LuaTeX is detected in PDF mode and

1. LaTeX is running (plain TeX users are on their own),
2. and shell escape (\write18) is enabled (possibly restricted),
3. and \DoNotLoadEpstopdf either does not exist or is not \relax.

For convenience the package `epstopdf` provides a macro to define a graphics rule
with conversion program (**1.5.3 Conversion program**):

```
\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{%
  convert #1 \OutputFile         
}
```

Also the backtick notation with `\DeclareGraphicsRule` can be used:

```
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{%
  \noexpand\epstopdfcall{convert #1 \noexpand\OutputFile}%
}
```

- `\noexpand` is needd, because `\DeclareGraphicsRule` expands the argument.
- `\epstopdfcall` deals with packages like `pst2pdf`.

The name of the output file `\OutputFile` is controlled by options. Since version 2009/07/12 v2.0 the default for option `suffix` is

```
suffix=-\SourceExt-converted-to
```

The suffix is inserted after the base name and the new file extension.
`foo.tif` becomes `foo-tif-converted-to.png`.

Comment: Well, it seems I did really not know the power of eps2pdf package. 
Thanks for this explanation, it seems to be the proper way to do it.

Comment: After checking at home on my windows, it seems that your second solution doesn't work, at least under this system. 
You might also add in your answer that the backtick notation **SHOULD NOT** be used in the first (and working) solution, because it is not portable to windows.

Comment: Thanks for testing. It was an error in the documentation. `\epstopdfcall` already adds the back tick.

Comment: Also make sure `imagemagick` is built with tiff support: `convert -list configure |grep DELEGATES`.

Answer (score 8):

Macros defined with `\newrobustcmd` (from `etoolbox`) are *not* expanded in `\write` operations. However `\filename@parse` relies on assignments which aren't performed in those operations.

I suggest to define

```
\def\eattif#1.tif{#1}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 \eattif#1-tif-converted-to.png }
\AppendGraphicsExtensions{.tif}
```

so that the extension will be swallowed (in an expandable fashion).

Comment: beat me by 45 seconds (I'll delete mine)

Comment: well, this seems very nice and simple.
Before accepting it, i have two questions. 
First I'm not really sure I understand your second sentance. do you imply that `\filename@parse` wouldn't work anyway ? Secondly, when testing your answer I discovered that in fact, `#1` doesn't seem to contain the extention under linux. 
Is it the same under every system (in which case it means I'm dumb and my question souldn't even be there in the first place -_-") ?

Comment: Well, this was really usefull and I still would really like to hear some clarifications about your second sentence. 
@Heiko 's answer however seems to be the most proper way to deal with this question, so I'll accept his one instead (or should I accept both ? I really have no clue).

Comment: @SamuelAlbert Surely Heiko's answer is more general.