# How to include images

Tags: graphics

I am trying to include math pictures in my document.

I have added

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
```

These two packages inside the header
 and then the following code

```
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.8cm}
\begin{picture}(6,5)
\put(3.5,0.4){$\displaystyle
s:=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$}
\put(1,1){\includegraphics[
  width=2cm,height=2cm]{picture.eps}}
\end{picture}
```

However, I keep on getting `error: picture.eps is missing`

Q: Do I need to create a directory where to store these pictures?
Q: What should be the location of this directory?
Q: What kind of file extensions do I need to have for these files?

Comment: This looks like a more detailed version of your [first question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98238/graphics-question). If this is so, please delete one of the two questions (perhaps the older one).

Comment: The easiest route is to put your `.eps` files in the same folder than your `tex` file. This answer, however can be elaborated if you want the figures in a different folder, or if your "main document" is indeed a bunch of `tex` files in different folders.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

What I typically do is to create a folder, say `figures`, to organize all images. The folder hierarchy would be:

```
latex-project/
    figures/
        foxjumpingoverdog.jpg
        ...
    document.tex
    ...
```

Then add the command `\graphicspath{./figures/}` in the preamble of the document to point to the folder.

Using the package `epstopdf` allows us to incorporate `.eps` figures.

A MWE followed by the output is below:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}
\noindent The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. See Figure~\ref{fig:figurelbl}.

    \begin{figure}[h]
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{foxjumpingoverdog}
      \caption{\label{fig:figurelbl} An illustration of the quick brown fox \emph{jumping} over the lazy dog.}
    \end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

[image: snapshot]

Comment: I want to thank you for answering my question. It is clear that now I can add pictures where I want.

Comment: My pleasure @RakeshSharma. If you think you have the right answer, you may choose to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: +1 for the `epstopdf` package

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness...

> Q: Do I need to create a directory where to store these pictures?
>
> Q: What should be the location of this directory?

It is not necessary to put the figures (or other files required for the typesetting of the document, as `tex` files, `bib` files, etc...) into specific directories. This means that you can organize your files in a way that suits to you, and `latex` and friends can be persuaded to adapt to your structure. It is just a matter of specifiyng the path unambiguously. Defining a relative path as Umar Kalim does in his answer is a good practice, minimizing both keystrokes and errors.

> Q: What kind of file extensions do I need to have for these files?

If you want to include figures, you will probably want to use the `includegraphics` command from the `graphicx` package. If you specify the filename without extension, as in `\includegraphics{path/to/file}`, the `eps` extension will be added when compiling with `latex`, and the `pdf` extension will be added when compiling with `pdflatex` (for this to work the two versions of the file should be present in the same directory).

The file types supported natively are:

- `latex`: can include EPS files with `graphicx` package (some `dvi` viewers may fail to show the image though)
- `pdflatex`: according to the manual page,

  > In  PDF  mode, pdfTeX can natively handle the PDF, JPG, JBIG2, and PNG graphics formats.

  As stated in Umar's answer, with the `epstopdf` package it is possible to include `eps` graphics into `pdf` files (the package automatically converts the file to `pdf` format, so the tool `epstopdf` needs to be present in your system)

If your file is not in any of these formats, it has to be converted to one of the above mentioned. Automatic conversions (i.e., performed by `(pdf)latex` at compilation time) can be forced using the `\DeclareGraphicsRule` command: take a look at [Using macros in \DeclareGraphicsRule statement using shell command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66943/using-macros-in-declaregraphicsrule-statement-using-shell-command), [Add tif image to LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89989/add-tif-image-to-latex?lq=1) and related questions.